# How to avoid Null pointer exception in springboot kotlin application

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have declared everything properly in my entity class and DTO class but when I pass the values in some interfaces when I call that interface in controller class at run time I get a null pointer exception. But in my application I use ? to avoid null pointer exception, but it still throws null pointer exception and indicates that null pointer exception occurred in my service class and controller class

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.nilmani.workmanagement.service.MaterialReturnService.acceptMaterial(MaterialReturnService.kt:35) ~[main/:na]
    at com.nilmani.workmanagement.controller.AdminWorkController.depositMaterial(AdminWorkController.kt:37) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

MaterialReturn.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workmanagement.model.request

import java.time.LocalDateTime

data class ReqMaterialReturn(
    val userId:Long?=-1,
    val withdrawId:Long?=-1,
    val deposit:Long?=-1,
    val totalPiecesMaterial:Long=-1,
    val pending:Long? = totalPiecesMaterial- deposit!!,
    val workStatus:Boolean?=false,
    val workPrice : Double?= deposit?.times(3.5),
    val depositedAt: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now()
)
```

Repository.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workmanagement.repository


import com.nilmani.workmanagement.entity.MaterialReturn
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
import javax.transaction.Transactional

interface MaterialReturnRepository : JpaRepository<MaterialReturn?, Long?> {

    // @Query("select u from WithdrawMaterial u where u.pieces =:pieces  AND u.withdrawId=:withdrawId")
    @Query("select m.pieces from WithdrawMaterial  as m where m.withdrawId =:withdrawId")
    fun findByWithdrawId(@RequestParam("withdrawId") withdrawId: Long?): Long?

}
```

MaterialReturnService.kt

```java
package com.nilmani.workmanagement.service

import com.nilmani.workmanagement.entity.MaterialReturn
import com.nilmani.workmanagement.model.request.ReqMaterialReturn
import com.nilmani.workmanagement.repository.MaterialReturnRepository
import com.nilmani.workmanagement.repository.UserRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import java.time.LocalDateTime

@Service
class MaterialReturnService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var materialReturnRepository: MaterialReturnRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository


    fun acceptMaterial(request:ReqMaterialReturn):MaterialReturn {
        val depositMaterial = MaterialReturn(
            userId = request.userId!!,
            withdrawId = request.withdrawId!!,
            deposit = request.deposit!!,
            totalPiecesMaterial = materialReturnRepository.findByWithdrawId(request.withdrawId)!!
        )
        return materialReturnRepository.save(depositMaterial)

    }
}
```

AdminWorkController.kt
package com.nilmani.workmanagement.controller

```
import com.nilmani.workmanagement.model.request.ReqMaterialReturn
import com.nilmani.workmanagement.model.request.RespWithdrawMaterial
import com.nilmani.workmanagement.model.response.RespMaterialReturn
import com.nilmani.workmanagement.service.MaterialReturnService
import com.nilmani.workmanagement.service.WorkService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/work")
class AdminWorkController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var workService: WorkService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var materialReturnService: MaterialReturnService
 
    @PostMapping("/deposit")
    fun depositMaterial(@ModelAttribute request:ReqMaterialReturn):ResponseEntity<*>{
        val depositMaterial = materialReturnService.acceptMaterial(request)
        val respDepositMaterial = RespMaterialReturn(
            depositMaterial.userId,
            depositMaterial.withdrawId,
            depositMaterial.deposit,
            depositMaterial.totalPiecesMaterial,
            depositMaterial.pending,
            depositMaterial.workPrice,
            depositMaterial.depositedAt
        )
        return ResponseEntity(respDepositMaterial,HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception in these two lines:

```
val depositMaterial = materialReturnService.acceptMaterial(request)
totalPiecesMaterial = materialReturnRepository.findByWithdrawId(request.withdrawId)
```

The first line is present in a controller class and the second line is present in my service class. When I assign `withdrawId` to `totalpieceMaterial` with the help calling `findByWithdrawId` function from the repository, the `request.withdrawId` is null.

Comment: I think first of all you should check in your controller whether request object is passed to your controller method or not, if yes, then check in your database is there a Withdraw with the following id (withdrawId)

Comment: Could you look at MaterialReturnService.kt line 35 like the error is stating...It might be that the request you are passing is actually null or your repository inside MaterialReturnService is null